433 mhz RGB Transmitter Remote
Does anyone know the number of this IC?
I know that IC number PT2262 or HT12E is used for transmitters. But I don't know what IC is used in this circuit and I am very interested to know how 21 keys are activated with this IC.



Hi! Welcome here! But: this question is neither about amateur radio nor about the general technology and theory of radio, but about the practical side of something that is decidedly not amateur radio! So, I'm afraid it's off-topic here. You could ask that at electronics.stackexchange.com, but they will tell you the following: This is a 16 pin IC with the markings removed, it's impossible to identify it, and even if you could, it probably would be just some general purpose microcontroller with a firmware you don't have burned in. So, that wouldn't help you. But:

to know what is transmitted when you press which button, you'd anyway just observe the signals coming out of your remote when you press that button, so knowing the chip wouldn't help that much. Just break out your SDR (you even use that tag!) and record.

HT12E is from HOLTEK and does the serial encoding for the separate transmitter.
